# How can I pass URL(link to a site) using local JSON parsing into my poject

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swiftui

[image: Here is Json parsing code][image: I am trying to use url(variable 'site') as information type, defining it String but my app crashes causing this thread. How can i resolve this?]

I am trying to use url(variable 'site') as information type, defining it String but my app crashes causing this thread. How can i resolve this?

Comment: Please share the snippet of your codable struct, something wrong in struct model

Answer (score 0):

Can you show where you fetch and parse the JSON in your code? Also perhaps the `Codable` struct you are using to handle the JSON.

Something like this:

```
func parseJSON() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/friendface.json") else { return }

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([CitizenData].self, from: data) {
                // Back to main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // update UI
                    self.results = decodedResponse

                    // Save to core data
                    self.saveToDevice(data: decodedResponse)
                }
                return
            }
        }
        print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
    }.resume()
}
```

A snippet of your JSON data might help too.

Comment: I am parsing Local JSON file into my project. Have a watch!